# Elasticsearch highlight on array, how to return entire array

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do some highlighting in Elasticsearch and am having difficulty getting the output I'd like for multi-value fields. Here's what I'm doing now:

```
{ "query" : { "match": { "nameSet": "test" } }, 
  "highlight" : { "fields" : { "*": {"number_of_fragments": 0 } } }
}
```

This gives me (omitted unnecessary fields):

```
"hits" : [ {
    ...
    "_source" : {
        "nameSet" : ["TEST", "NAME"]
    },
    "highlight" : {
       "nameSet" : [ "<em>TEST</em>" ]
    }
 }, 
 ...
```

What I would like to have is the full array, and not just the item that matched. In this example, I would like "TEST" to be emphasized and "NAME" to be present but not emphasized.

```
"hits" : [ {
    ...
    "_source" : {
        "nameSet" : ["TEST", "NAME"]
    },
    "highlight" : {
       "nameSet" : [ "<em>TEST</em>", "NAME" ] 
    }
 }, 
 ...
```

Any way to do this purely in ES?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to introduce a field for concatenated array items and update the docs by query

Mapping

```
PUT /array_highlighting
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name_set": {
                "type": "text",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
            },
            "name_set_concatenated": {
                "type": "text",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Document

```
PUT /array_highlighting/_doc/1
{
    "name_set": ["TEST", "NAME"]
}
```

Update by query

```
POST /array_highlighting/_update_by_query
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script": {
        "source": """
            def items = ctx._source[params.source_field_name];
            String concatenatedItems = String.join(params.item_delimiter, items);
            ctx._source[params.destination_field_name] = concatenatedItems;
        """,
        "params": {
            "item_delimiter": ", ",
            "source_field_name": "name_set",
            "destination_field_name": "name_set_concatenated"
        }
    }
}
```

Search query

```
GET /array_highlighting/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name_set": "test"
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "*": {
                "type": "fvh",
                "matched_fields": ["name_set", "name_set_concatenated"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response isn't an array, but an array-like string

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "array_highlighting",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 0.18232156,
                "_source" : {
                    "name_set_concatenated" : "TEST, NAME",
                    "name_set" : [
                        "TEST",
                        "NAME"
                    ]
                },
                "highlight" : {
                    "name_set_concatenated" : [
                        "<em>TEST</em>, NAME"
                    ],
                    "name_set" : [
                        "<em>TEST</em>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Inside of highlight object you can use pre and post tags. For example:

```
"hits" : [ {
    ...
    "_source" : {
        "nameSet" : ["TEST", "NAME"]
    },
    "highlight" : {
       "pre_tags": "<em>",
       "post_tags": "</em>",
       "nameSet" : [ "<em>TEST</em>", "NAME" ] 
    }
 }, 
 ...
```